# Python Read a list from a file and assign to a new list

Tags: python, list, readfile

I have a text file that contains a list
This is what the list in the file like

```
[['1', 'a', 66, 66, 66, 66], ['1', 'b', 77, 77, 77, 77], ['1', 'c', 77, 88, 88, 88], ['1', '', 99, 99, 99, 99], ['3', 'd', 76, 87, 98, 78], ['3', 'e', 67, 90, 76, 89], ['3', 'f', 77, 99, 77, 66], ['3', 'g', 77, 88, 99, 77]]
```

I do have one that works that does not read the file it just iterates through a list

```
i=0
j=0
k=0
m=0
n=0
p=0
total=0
TeamInfo = []
TeamScores = []
while i < 2:
    TeamName = input("Enter Team Name:")
    while j < 4:
        TeamMember = (input("Enter Player's Name:"))
        j+=1
        TeamInfo.append([TeamName, TeamMember])
    j = 0
    i+=1



while k < 8:
    while m < 4:
        getScore = "Please Enter Score # "+str(m+1)+" for team member " +str(TeamInfo[k][1])+":" 
        Score = int(input(getScore))
        while Score < 65 or Score > 115:
            Score = int(input(getScore))
        TeamInfo[k].append(Score)
        m+=1
    
    m = 0
    k+=1

try:
    with open("Golf_Team_Info.txt", "a") as w:
            w.write("%s\n" %TeamInfo)
            w.close
except:
    print("File does not exist")


for n in range(len(TeamInfo)):
    total = sum(filter(lambda j: isinstance(j, int),TeamInfo[n]))
    avg = total/4
    Name = str(TeamInfo[n][1])
    TeamScores.append([Name, total])
    print("Score for Team Member:", TeamInfo[n][1], "on Team", TeamInfo[n][0], "is",total, "with a avegrage score of", avg)



r = open("Golf_Team_Info.txt", "r")
print(r.read())
for p in range(len(TeamScores)):
    if p == 0:
        lowest = TeamScores[0][1]
        winner = TeamScores[0][0]
    elif lowest > TeamScores[p][1]:
        lowest = TeamScores[p][1]
        winner = TeamScores[p][0]
print("The player with the lowest score is" ,winner,"with a score of",lowest)
```

When I use the read file I would like to go through the list and read the elements in it but when I do it doesn't comes up as a list and when I try to read an item in the element I get a index out of range

```
p = "Golf_Team_Info.txt"
n = 0
j = 0
TeamInfo = []
with open(p,'r+') as scores:
     test = scores.readline()
     TeamInfo = test

for n in range(len(TeamInfo)):
    total = sum(filter(lambda j: isinstance(j, int),TeamInfo[n]))
    avg = total/4
    Name = str(TeamInfo[n][1])
    TeamScores.append([Name, total])
    print("Score for Team Member:", TeamInfo[n][1], "on Team", TeamInfo[n][0], "is",total, "with a avegrage score of", avg)
```

Comment: I ran a test on the one that is working to get the length of TeamInfo and it returns a length of 8. The one that is being read returns a length of 224

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` to turn a list in string format `"[1,2,3]"` to an actual list `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: using ast.literal_eval gave me the correct length

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark Tolonen for pointing me to ast.literal_eval
Got my code working now

```
import ast
r = "Golf_Team_Info.txt"
n = 0
p = 0
TeamScores = []
with open(r,'r+') as scores:
     test = scores.readline()
     TeamInfo = ast.literal_eval(test)

for n in range(len(TeamInfo)):
    total = sum(filter(lambda j: isinstance(j, int),TeamInfo[n]))
    avg = total/4
    Name = str(TeamInfo[n][1])
    TeamScores.append([Name, total])
    print("Score for Team Member:", TeamInfo[n][1], "on Team", TeamInfo[n][0], "is",total, "with a avegrage score of", avg)
for p in range(len(TeamScores)):
    if p == 0:
        lowest = TeamScores[0][1]
        winner = TeamScores[0][0]
    elif lowest > TeamScores[p][1]:
        lowest = TeamScores[p][1]
        winner = TeamScores[p][0]
print("The player with the lowest score is" ,winner,"with a score of",lowest)
```